# Why shiny didn't call local function in server session?

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose I have a local function:

```
getres<-function(x, y){
   x^2-y
}
```

Then I have shiny::server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  reslst<-reactive({
    getres(input$x, input$y)
  })

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    reslst
  })
}
```

When I execute the code, it reported no object `reslst` which means the local function `getres` hasn't run at all. Some suggestions?

Comment: have a read at this page: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: What you do mean "it reported no object `reslst`"? Do you have a test for it?

Comment: Do you mean `output$result <- renderPrint({ reslst(); })` instead? (Notice the parens ... reactive data is typically *called*, not just referenced.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling your function inside the server argument?

```
server <- function(input, output) {

getres<-function(x, y){
   x^2-y
}

reslst<-reactive({
    getres(input$x, input$y)
  })

  output$result <- renderPrint({
    reslst
  })
}
```